# Changing default date format in trac queries

Tags: trac, date-format

I have a trac (http://trac.edgewall.org/) bug tracking system where I have admin priveledges, but no access to the actual server. I got the guy who has access to the server to install  the iniadmin plugin (http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/IniAdminPlugin) so I can actually get some stuff done without bothering him.

My problem is that when I do a ticket-query, all of the dates are displayed in terms of "3 days ago" or "1 month ago". I want the actual date.

I've been told that the way to do this is to change the ticket template, or change the default date-format from "datesense" to "long". However, I can't figure out where to do this.

Is there another TracHack I need to get installed? Is it impossible to do this remotely?

thanks!

ETA: If there's a better cousin-site that I this should be moved to, let me know!

Answer (score 0):

To change the ticket template, you do need access to the server.

If you hover the mouse over the date, you should get a tooltip that displays the actual date/timestamp.  Since this information is already included in the HTML of the page, you should be able to use some Javascript to swap the text of the link with the text from the link's tooltip (my javascript skills are terrible or I'd give you some sample code).  You would need server access to make this change globally, but you can use a browser plugin like Greasemonkey to run the javascript on the page locally.  Doing that would fix the problem for you, but other users would need to do the same in their browser to get the same benefit.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://trac.edgewall.org/ticket/11659), it is possible on trac 1.0. I have no such configuration in the admin panel in Trac 1.0.2.

But if you have access to *config/trac.ini*, you can set `default_dateinfo_format` in `[trac]` section to `absolute` instead of `relative`.